# Cooking at low temperature on induction cooktop

Tags: temperature, induction

I started cooking recently on induction cooktop ,minimum temperature on it is 120 C but i want to cook my dish at 50 C for 15 minutes but the temperature is increasing rapidly.How do i maintain its temperature?

Comment: 50 C is pretty cool.  That is more like warm for 15 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a water bath and see if it will stay low enough for the desired time. You can play around with the water amount to achieve more consistency.

Even with the water bath, you won't get actual 50 degrees for 15 minutes, rather you'll have some slowly rising temperature which will stay in a hopefully acceptable range for the 15 minutes. This is because a cooktop is simply the wrong tool for the job, and especially the induction ones can be worse than the oldtime ones.

If you really want low temperatures for a sustained time, use an oven (if yours goes that low) or an electronically controlled cooking device.